# pass value from usercontrol to another in same usercontrol wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

i have four user control , i tried to pass value from usercontrol to another , these usercontrols is exist in same usercontrol.
this main xml  page

```
`    <Grid>
    <StackPanel  Background="#FFF">

        <local:mwidget x:Name="mwidget"  Loaded="UserControl1_Loaded"/>
        <local:addemploy x:Name="addemploy" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <local:editemploy x:Name="editemploy"  Visibility="Hidden"  />           
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>`
```

and this code

```
`    private void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mwidget.ShowUserControl2Requested += OnShowUserControl2Requested;
        addemploy.ShowUserControl1Requested += OnShowUserControl1Requested;

        editemploy.ShowUserControl1Requestedd += ShowUserControl1Requestedd;
        mwidget.ShowUserControl2Requestedd += ShowUserControl1Requesteddd;
     
    }

    private void OnShowUserControl2Requested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addemploy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        mwidget.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnShowUserControl1Requested(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mwidget.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        addemploy.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    private void ShowUserControl1Requestedd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mwidget.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        editemploy.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    private void ShowUserControl1Requesteddd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        editemploy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    
        mwidget.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }`
```

and this code mwidget

```
`    public partial class mwidget : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ShowUserControl2Requested;
    public event EventHandler ShowUserControl2Requestedd;
   
    public mwidget()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  
    private void add_employ(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ShowUserControl2Requested?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }
   

    private void edit_employ(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


            ShowUserControl2Requestedd?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

}`

so i want pass value from mwidget to editemploy, i tried some solutions but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a DependencyProperties  in mwidget and editemploy and bind them to each other. (Note: in the example below, I used OneWay.  This prevents editemploy from changing the value in mwidget.  If you do not want that then change it to TwoWay.)

mwidget:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MyValue),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(mwidget));

public bool MyValue
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(MyValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyValueProperty, value);
}
```

editemploy:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPassedValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MyPassedValue),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(editemploy));

public bool MyPassedValue
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(MyPassedValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyPassedValueProperty, value);
}
```

xaml:

```
<local:mwidget x:Name="mwidget"  Loaded="UserControl1_Loaded"/>
<local:addemploy x:Name="addemploy" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<local:editemploy x:Name="editemploy" 
                  Visibility="Hidden"
                  MyPassedValue="{Binding ElementName=mwidget, Path=MyValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: not work its display  The member "MyPassedValue" is not recognized or is not accessible

Comment: thank you so much, its work fine after reload project